# Tips and tricks for fast Magento2 localhost development

Tags: magento2, cache, development, localhost

Does anyone has some ideas or tips for improving magento2's performance on localhost taking into consideration that you are working without cache and other stuff that helps the loading speed.

How much do you think it affects the OS in this matter ? (Windows vs Linux vs OS X)

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Maximum performance you gets definitely on Linux. OS X also good enough (except case insensitive file system by default). I don't recommend use Windows. Is not supported for Magento and require use virtualization for proper work.

- **I never run compiler and static deploy scripts!!!**
- I use Macbook Pro as Developer computer.
- I setup Magento in vagrant
  (on ubuntu) with 2G memory and use **NFS** for file sharing.
- I use developer mode.
- I always enable all caches (except when a start
  modify the layout. than I disable FP, Blocks, and Layout cache).
- I use PHP7 with opcache (configured to recheck files every second) and enable  xdebug extension only if need to debug (iI have the script that fully enable/disable extension in php, not just debugging - **it's improve performance in 3-5 times!!!**).
- I use APCLite for cache adapter

Answer (score 0):

@Dragos, I've ran into the same problem. I'm on a Macbook Pro with: 16GB RAM, 2.8Ghz i7 cpu, and SSD. I have noticed that when I spin up an AWS EC2 instance with roughly the same specs, an M2 installation is *much* faster. The EC2 instance also wasn't running all the local processes that I was. Last time I checked, 750MB was the minimum suggested RAM to be allocated to an instance. 
For local development:

1. Make sure you have enough free RAM for M2 to run
2. Try using Less.js, instead of having Magento transpile your Less (in developer mode)
3. When in developer mode, deploy your static content up front, and then only delete the files related to what you've modified (so that your changes will be reflected upon page load. If you deploy static content up front, but do *not* then delete the corresponding generated file, you will not see your changes reflected).
4. For my setup, I use Docker and have configured Zend OpCache for Php, and I use Varnish (obviously clearing of cache is required to see changes reflected, but I got tired of the slow local speed. YMMV).

I hope these ideas help.

Comment: To minimize  memory usage disable PERFORMANCE_SHEME in MySql. (it's - 200M)

Comment: Newer deploy static file in development mode!!!

Comment: @KAndy: In development mode, deploying static files just creates all of the symlinks up front, instead of forcing each one to be created on-demand through a PHP request. It can save a lot of time.

Comment: @RyanH., no, deploy did file copy and when you change original file you need delete  copied version. It is common mistake.

Comment: @KAndy that's why I put "and then only delete the files related to what you've modified" meaning, delete the files that you've modified, so that the new files will be generated (so that you can see your changes reflected). If this portion of my answer was not present, then I would totally agree with you. Maybe I wasn't clear enough and assumed the OP understood my answer. My apologies.

Comment: @KAndy updated my answer to be a bit clearer.